# React Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replace')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just learning React and I'm designing a webstore project, I got this error in my ShoppingList when defining the variables and values , thank you for your help.

> ({value === "all" && items.map((item) => (
> <Item item={item} key={`${item.name}-${item.id}`} />
> ))}
> {value === "newArrivals" && items.map((item) => (
> <Item item={item} key={`${item.name}-${item.id}`} />
> ))}
> {value === "bestSellers" && items.map((item) => (
> <Item item={item} key={`${item.name}-${item.id}`} />
> ))}
> {value === "topRated" && items.map((item) => (
> <Item item={item} key={`${item.name}-${item.id}`} />
> ))})

Comment: I don't think the error is caused by anything you pasted here .. In your code you must be calling the replace() function somewhere.

Comment: Try creating a [mcve] and adding that to your question. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).